# Capture image for processing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, webcam

I'm using Python with PIL and SciPy.
i want to capture an image from a webcam then process it further using numpy and Scipy. Can somebody please help me out with the code.

Here is the code there is a predefined image "lena" but I wish to use my own captured image instead of the "lena" image. What changes do I make to the code?

```
from scipy import misc
lena = misc.lena()
lx, ly = lena.shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
crop_lena = lena[lx / 4: - lx / 4, ly / 4: - ly / 4]
plt.imshow(crop_lena)
```

Another example

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
l = scipy.misc.lena()
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3.6))
plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(l, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Video Capture by Markus Gritsch](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/)

I've used a lot [Video Capture by Markus Gritsch](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) and this maybe is the simplest and fastest way to do what you want.

```
from VideoCapture import Device
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image
cam = Device(devnum=0, showVideoWindow=0) #devnum=0 means you are using the device set in 0 position probably your webcam
blackimg= cam.getImage() #this return a PIL image but I don't know why the first is always black
#blackimag.show()#try to check if you want
image=cam.getImage() #this is a real image PIL image
imgarray = asarray(image) #convert the image into a matrix
#imgarrayfloat = imgarray.astype('float') # in many cases of processing you have to convert to a float matrix because can occur overflow (e.g. for average images summing  pixels values of 255 and 3 of two images and divide by 2 gives you 1/2 for imgarray and 258/2 for imgarrayfloat 
#recovertedimage=processedimage.astype ("uint8")#if you use the previous you have to reconvert to unit8. Note processedimage is the name of the variable of your image.
```

## [Python OpenCV: cv2 & cv](http://opencv.org/)

You can do it with Python binding for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) too. There are at least two ways for do that. I've found [this](http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/capture-images-and-video-from-camera-in-opencv-2-3-1/) and [this](http://codeplasma.com/2012/12/03/getting-webcam-images-with-python-and-opencv-2-for-real-this-time/) tutorial interesting.

#### [Video Capture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#VideoCapture)

```
from cv2 import *
cam = VideoCapture(0)  #set the port of the camera as before
retval, image = cam.read() #return a True bolean and and the image if all go right
cam.release() #Closes video file or capturing device.
```

In this case you have a `numpy.ndarray` (no more PIL image) so to show the image type in the shell:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)
```

#### Old way with CaptureFromCAM

```
import cv2.cv as cv 
import numpy as np  
Capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
image = cv.QueryFrame(Capture) #here you have an IplImage
imgarray = np.asarray(image[:,:]) #this is the way I use to convert it to numpy array
```

You can show it as above.

Comment: Unfortunately VideoCapture doesn't seem to have been updated in 4 years, and just works on Windows.

Comment: The cv2 example works if you add `plt.show()` to the end, unfortunately the color is waay off.

Comment: @NoBugs colors are off probably because cv by default use not RGB, but BGR channels. So you probably need to convert it with `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` (i know it was 7 years ago, but since nobody mentioned it before, i hope it can be of use to someone)

Answer (score 4):

You can use VideoCapture lib to get the picture from a USB camera.

```
from VideoCapture import Device

came = Device()
came.setResolution(320, 240)

img = cam.getImage()
...
```