# TensorFlow model correctly predicting images, but not frames from real time video stream?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, video-streaming

Why does my TensorFlow model **correctly predict JPG and PNG images** but **incorrectly predict frames from real time video stream?** All frames in the real time video stream are all being incorrectly classified as class 1.

Attempt: I saved a PNG image from the realtime video stream. When I saved the PNG image separately and tested it, the model correctly classifies it. When a similar image is a frame in the real time video stream it is incorrectly classified. The PNG images and real time video stream frames have identical content visually (background, lighting condition, camera angle, etc.).

Structure of my model:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
rescaling_2 (Rescaling)      (None, 180, 180, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 180, 180, 16)      448
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 90, 90, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 90, 90, 32)        4640
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 45, 45, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 45, 45, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 22, 22, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 30976)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               3965056
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 387
=================================================================
Total params: 3,989,027
Trainable params: 3,989,027
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Found 1068 files belonging to 3 classes.
```

Realtime prediction code: (updated after Keertika's help!)

```
def testModel(imageName):
  import cv2
  from PIL import Image
  from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
  batch_size = 32
  img_height = 180
  img_width = 180
  img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
  imageName,
  target_size=(img_height, img_width),
  interpolation = "bilinear",
  color_mode = 'rgb'
  )
 
  #preprocessing different here
  img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) #Create a batch
 
  predictions = new_model.predict(img_array)
  score = predictions[0]
  classes = ['1', '2','3']
prediction = classes[np.argmax(score)]
 
  print(
      "This image {} most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
      .format(imageName, classes[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
  )
 
  return prediction
```

Training code:

```
#image_dataset_from_directory returns a tf.data.Dataset that yields batches of images from 
#the subdirectories class_a and class_b, together with labels 0 and 1.
from keras.preprocessing import image
directory_test = "/content/test"
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory_test, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256,
    256), shuffle=True, seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)
 
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory_test, labels='inferred')
 
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  directory_test,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Is the accuracy being affected by the reshaping in the realtime prediction code? I do not understand why frame predictions are incorrect, but single JPG and PNG image predictions are correct. Thank you for any help!

Comment: throw some `.copy()` in there, see if that makes a difference

Comment: Can you please explain where to use .copy() and why? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use .copy() to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you load and save the image files? If you dont use opencv for loading then maybe BGR vs. RGB is the problem. Plase share the code where everything is working well with savee images.

Comment: I've shared the code for my testModel function. The testModel function uses the tensorflow model predict function to accurately predict PNG and JPG images. This same tensorflow model predict function results in incorrectly predicting all real time frames as the same incorrect classification.

Comment: Your working example uses keras.preprocessing.image.load_img to load the image file. This is probably a different format (I guess RGB instead of BGR which is deluvered by  cv2.imread) and maybe even doing some additional preprocessing and maybe different interpolation during resizing.

Comment: In your Videocapture code try frame = cv2.cvtColor with BGR2RGB code. If necessary use INTER_NEAREST in cv2.resize.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with BGR2RGB and using INTER_NEAREST in cv2.resize. Unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue. All images are still being inaccurately predicted as the same incorrect gesture in the livestream. I've edited my question with the code suggestion you made for you to view. Can you please explain your thought process being using INTER_NEAREST? Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: On PNG and JPG images my model is able to accurately predict both BGR and RGB images.

Comment: It's interesting why frames in the realtime video stream that appear to be the same as PNG and JPG images I have tested are not predicted accurately. I'm having trouble understanding why.

Comment: Because https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img uses "nearest" interpolation. Your processing pipelines are quite (argmax in one vetsion, softmax in the other, etc.). I would try to just replace the image loading by the videocapture+transformation and keep EVERYTHING else as in the working code. Then analyze the remaining differences in the data.

Comment: Here's a way to capture images as PLT images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994544/capture-image-for-processing

Comment: Thank you Micka. What would be the benefit of capturing images as PLT images v CV2?

Comment: I have not included the testModel function in my videocapture code :) I included the testModel function to show that the model does work on PNG & JPG images.  So i've already replayed the image loading by the videocapture+transformation. Can you please explain what you mean by analyzing the remaining differences in data? The differences between frame data and training data? (because videocapture frame data and training data should be of the same types?) What other types of differences and data do you suggest I analyze for?

Comment: I've added my code for creating the training dataset. I see that I've used interpolation='bilinear' when creating the training dataset which is not consistent with interpolation in resizing the frame in VideoCapture. I'll try to changing the training interpolation to nearest interpolation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for the real time prediction not correct is because of the preprocessing. The preprocessing of the inference code should be always same as the preprocessing used while training. Use **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img** in your real-time prediction code but it takes image path to load the image. so you can save each frame by name **"sample.png"** and pass this path to **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img**. this should solve the issue. and use the resize method **"bilinear"** because that was used for training data

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238820/discussion-on-answer-by-keertika-jain-tensorflow-model-correctly-predicting-imag).